# Can't run fsck or format device - device is in use

Tags: linux, filesystems, mdadm, block-device

today I crashed my boot partition. While is normally no problem due backups, I can't write to the partition anymore.

```
root@hades ~ # touch /boot/a
touch: cannot touch '/boot/a': Structure needs cleaning
```

dmesg shows me:

```
[317873.920810] EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_find_dest_de:1932: inode #2: block 518: comm touch: bad entry in directory: rec_len is smaller than minimal - offset=0, inode=0, rec_len=0, name_len=0, size=1024
```

Even after successfully umount the device, I can't fsck

```
root@hades ~ # umount /boot
root@hades ~ # e2fsck /dev/md2
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/md2 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.


root@hades ~ # fsck.ext4 /dev/md2
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/md2 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

I'm unable to reformat or destroy the partition:

```
root@hades ~ # wipefs /dev/md2
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE UUID                                 LABEL
md2    0x438  ext4 2112045a-2e84-4c69-8c67-d76e8ad7a13a boot
root@hades ~ # wipefs -a /dev/md2
wipefs: error: /dev/md2: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
root@hades ~ # mkfs.ext4 -L boot /dev/md2
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/md2 contains a ext4 file system labelled 'boot'
    last mounted on /boot on Fri Sep 18 21:33:34 2020
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
/dev/md2 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

I also can't stop the mdam array to set the while raid array to fail:

```
root@hades ~ # mdadm --stop /dev/md2 --force
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md2:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?


root@hades ~ # mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/nvme0n1p2 --remove /dev/nvme0n1p2
mdadm: set /dev/nvme0n1p2 faulty in /dev/md2
mdadm: hot removed /dev/nvme0n1p2 from /dev/md2
root@hades ~ # mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/nvme1n1p2 --remove /dev/nvme1n1p2
mdadm: set device faulty failed for /dev/nvme1n1p2:  Device or resource busy

mdadm --add /dev/md2 /dev/nvme0n1p2

root@hades ~ # mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/nvme1n1p2 --remove /dev/nvme1n1p2
mdadm: set /dev/nvme1n1p2 faulty in /dev/md2
mdadm: hot removed /dev/nvme1n1p2 from /dev/md2
root@hades ~ # mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/nvme0n1p2 --remove /dev/nvme0n1p2
mdadm: set device faulty failed for /dev/nvme0n1p2:  Device or resource busy
```

fuser or lsof does now shoe any process except kernel threads:

```
root@hades ~ # lsof | grep md2
md2_raid1     262                              root  cwd       DIR                9,4     4096          2 /
md2_raid1     262                              root  rtd       DIR                9,4     4096          2 /
md2_raid1     262                              root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/262/exe
jbd2/md2-     599                              root  cwd       DIR                9,4     4096          2 /
jbd2/md2-     599                              root  rtd       DIR                9,4     4096          2 /
jbd2/md2-     599                              root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/599/exe
root@hades ~ # fuser -v /dev/md2
root@hades ~ # fuser -v /dev
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev:                root     kernel mount /dev
                     root         57 .rc.. kdevtmpfs
```

I'm not using LVM, no userspace is installed:

```
root@hades ~ # vgs

Command 'vgs' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install lvm2
```

The mdadm RAID looks clean:

```
root@hades ~ # mdadm -D /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Jul 17 22:22:07 2019
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 523712 (511.44 MiB 536.28 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 523712 (511.44 MiB 536.28 MB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Tue Sep 22 14:30:52 2020
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:boot
              UUID : b8cce71f:11cb0913:e75f8623:0846cd86
            Events : 176

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       3     259        2        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p2
       2     259        9        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

```
Linux hades 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu
```

I can't restart the server, because the system isn't bootable now. Currently I do not have physical access to the machine.

I already shutdown all services except systemd, ssh, polkit, rsyslog and mdadm monitor.

How I could identify the source which is using the device?

Comment: Let's start with `sudo lsof -n | grep /boot`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Got no output.

Comment: `sudo mkfs.ext4 -f /dev/md2` then. Also check `dmesg` for errors.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I got `mkfs.ext4: invalid option -- 'f'`. I'm using `mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)`

Comment: Sorry, it's `-F` for mkfs.

Comment: I got this: `/dev/md2 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!` No additional logs in dmesg or syslog.

Comment: How did you "crash" your boot partition?

Comment: Using tune2fs wrongly. I tried to change the inode size, but I enter the wrong partition number. I want todo that on my data partition. After some hours, the entry in dmesg appears and the boot partion was unable to use anymore.

Comment: What do you get from `grep -Ei 'md2| / |boot' /proc/mounts`? (the lone `/` has a space either side)

Comment: @roaima One line back: `/dev/md4 / ext4 rw,relatime 0 0`

Comment: That's good. Just checking :-)

Comment: Have you tried booting a live CD and performing the fixes with it?

Comment: @kbulgrien No, since I do not have physical access to the machine nor the system have something like KVM. I'm pretty sure this problem could be fix by booting a live cd. But I'm looking for a solution w/o shutdown the running system.

Comment: Does https://serverfault.com/questions/286169/impossible-to-stop-raid-device or https://serverfault.com/questions/359561/mdadm-hot-remove-failed-for help or, for that matter other results of a search for "mdadm force fail when device busy"?

Comment: @kbulgrien Thanks for the links. I look into it but in both cases a raid member raises, e.g. hard disk raises "devices busy". In my case, the raid device it self is busy. Unlike in the both posts, I'm able to remove the hard disks one by one but I'm unable to remove all at once. You could see the output in the post above.

Comment: Additionally I long term google search in `mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to` does not provide any solutions. A reason for this post here.

Comment: Check nfs exports, too.

Comment: Why would anyone export their /boot via NFS? ;-)

Comment: No NFS configured on the server nor installed on this server.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this same problem.  It went away after I unmounted loopback devices created by snap.  Specifically, I did the following:

1. disabled all snaps (`snap list` to see the snaps, followed by `snap disable xyz` for each snap)
2. stopped `snapd` (`systemctl stop snapd`)
3. manually unmounted the loopback devices created by snap (`lsblk` to see them and `umount /snap/xyz/123` to unmount)

I'm not sure if all of the above steps are necessary, or if there's a better way to unmount the snaps.

Comment: Thank you for this. Also true for docker container which bind mounts. I stopped the docker container which was using files in the unmounted fs and now I can fsck.